# o que é mais rápido e leve para renderizar (ul-li ou table)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

estou fazendo um menu dinâmico com table (6 colunas já definidas e a linha vai variar) e bootstrap.
gostaria de saber qual é a melhor estrutura para se construir um menu dinâmico (o usuário vai escolher diversas opções, vai poder clonar a linha, etc)

```
for(var i =0; i< arrSequencia.length;i++ ){
strInterface += "<tr class='formulario'>"+
    "<td class='col-md-1'>"+
        "   <input type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger btn-info-bloco sembloco\" value=\"Botao "+arrSequencia[i]+"\"/>"+
        "</td>"+

    "</tr>";
}
```

estou implementando assim... ul-li é mais rápido e leve para se renderizar?

Comment: Eu diria que o mais rápido é fazeres isso no servidor... no HTML não me parece que haja diferênças relevantes.

Comment: o ideal é fazer esses menus dinâmicos no servidor? fiz tudo no html.

Comment: `ul-li` seria mais indicado para menus, já o `Table` é mais indicado e recomendado somente para mostrar dados.

Comment: como boa prática, o ideal é com ul-li então?

Comment: sim, o ideal e recomendado. `Table` só para mostrar dados.

Comment: @Denali, um pequeno conselho, no lugar de ficar montando o html na mão, tente usar alguma template engine para isto, fiz um pequeno exemplo usando o Handlebars(http://handlebarsjs.com): http://jsfiddle.net/xrkuj8w3/.
Acredito que isto pode simplificar o seu trabalho.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo creio que a melhor forma de se trabalhar hoje seria utilizando fixed data tables com react, com isso fica muita mais performático, da uma olhada no https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/ que você vai gostar.

Obs.: Alguém corrija-me caso esteja errado!

Comment: Mas a ideia é montar um menu e não uma lista de dados. Não seria interessante o uso de tabelas nisso. ;)